# Which is the alternate permission for reading bookmarks in Android M

Tags: android, android-permissions, user-permissions

My application is running fine in lollipop. But I am not able to find a solution to make it run in Android M. I am using the following two permissions for my application:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

In the Android M Developer preview docs google has stated that

"Bookmarks and subscribed feeds permissions are removed." in the following link:
http://developer.android.com/preview/support.html

So, the permissions used previously will not work for my application in Android M. If any one know any alternate permission that I can use which will make my application run as usual, please do let me know. I am trying to find solution from 15 days but I am not able to. Please provide your suggestions, If there is any alternate way please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it has been removed because they feel that modern browsers are no longer using the Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI to store bookmarks.

see [discussion on the issue here](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2805)

Update: page has been removed, here is a snapshot of the discussion
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the relevant text behind that link? That link requires a user to sign in with Google account credentials and then throws error 403.